Prevent terminal emulator from killing launched program upon closing
I'm trying something the lines of
alacritty -e ~/x.sh

where x.sh is
#!/usr/bin/env bash
f="$(fzf)"
xdg-open "$f" &
disown
sleep 1

However, when I run this in a terminal, the program opened by xdg-open closes when the timer elapses. This does not happen when call alacritty (or whatever terminal emulator) from dmenu, launch x.sh manually, and quit alacritty.
What does cause this behaviour, and how do I prevent the opened program from closing?

Try running read as the last command, or bash.

@choroba Doesn't that keep the terminal window open indefinitely?

You can close it by pressing Ctrl+D.

Have you try with nohup?

@RomeoNinov Yes, does not change the behaviour. And it would fail anyways if the program has its own sighup handler.
